# Having trouble using DispatcherPriority to access UI items outside of a given thread

Tags: c#, dispatcher

Using WPF:

Here's my MainWindow class:
[image]

Here's a snip from my Server class:
[image]

My server is receiving data over sockets, deserializing JSON data and converting it to a "record" struct. I am then updating a list of records with new record and displaying them on the UI via the MainWindow.grid property.

My initial problem was that WPF doesn't like background threads accessing UI elements, so after a quick Google search, I found that I must use "Dispatcher".

Line 125 throws an error "The name 'DispatcherPriority' does not exist in the current context.

What am I doing wrong? Am I on the right path?

Comment: Generally don't put screenshots of code. Put the code itself, click on the button that looks like `{ }` to make it format correctly if it is not formatted when you paste it.

Answer (score 0):

When you [look at a class on the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority(v=vs.110).aspx) you will see two peices of information at the top of the page

> **Namespace:**   System.Windows.Threading
>   **Assembly:**  WindowsBase (in WindowsBase.dll)

Namespace means the full name of the class is `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority`, that means your code either needs to use

```
.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, ...
```

or you need to put a `using System.Windows.Threading;` at the top of the file and you can use your code as-is.

You also need to make sure the assembly is referenced in your project. Check your project references and see that `WindowsBase` is in the list, and if it is not add it.